# can't spawn 2 bins in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all hope you al are fine.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ROS Kinetic version. I am working on UR5 robot simulation in Gazebo for which I made a custom catkin space and my own pkg named "ur5_custom" in this pkg I made launch file "custom_initialize.launch file" in which I am using the following:

node name="bin" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-file $(find ur5_notebook)/urdf/bin.urdf -urdf -model bin -y 0.8 -x -0.5 -z 0.05"

node name="bin1" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-file $(find ur5_notebook)/urdf/bin1.urdf -urdf -model bin -y 1 -x -1.5 z 0.05"

This is to spawn 2 bin in gazebo but it is not working. I received the following error:
[ERROR] [1640883635.252745507, 0.321000000]: SpawnModel: Failure - model name bin already exists.

I have tried same name different names, same urdf files and different(duplicate) URDF files also but no success at all.
please tell me how to spawn 2 same objects at different positons in gazebo using a single URDF file.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393565/can%27t-spawn-2-bins-in-gazebo/) by [umar_anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/82934/umar_anjum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue was resolved by adding a URDF directory in my workspace package and putting in box.urdf in it, where as it was in an other workspce in another package from which I was accessing it.  probably that was the problem. This is the piece of code I used instead of the above:

node name="bin" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-file $(find ur5_notebook)/urdf/bin.urdf -urdf -model bin -y 0.8 -x -0.5 -z 0.05"

node name="bin1" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-file $(find ur5_notebook)/urdf/bin.urdf -urdf -model bin1 -y 1 -x -1.5 -z 0.05"

node name is different also name just after -model before describing its coordinates.

---

Originally posted by [umar_anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/82934/umar_anjum/) with karma: 11 on 2022-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your second piece of code you don't have a minus next to `z`. There are no error pasted too. Can you add it?

By [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/52115/spawn-multiple-objects-in-gazebo/) only the name of the models should differ. You can use the same URDF many times. Does the part with `$(find ur5_notebook)` work correctly too? Can you try your launch file with the URDF file in the same folder?

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2021-12-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [umar_anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/82934/umar_anjum/) on 2022-01-01**:
I must have missed the - with z in the 2nd line of code but I have tried code with -z 0.05 too.

there are actually no errors just an error saying can't create a node of type spawn_model.

This code is creating 1 bin so I assume $(find ur5_notebook) is working as it is creating a bin.

I will try launching urdf within same folder havent yet tried that.